# How to check all checkboxes when the user visits the page for the first time?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want the checkboxes to be checked when the user visits the page for the first time.

This file is `app/views/movies/index.html.haml`

```
%h1 All Movies
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get, :id => 'ratings_form' do
  Include:
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", "1", @checked_ratings.include?(rating), :id => "ratings_#{rating}",
  = submit_tag 'Refresh', :id => 'ratings_submit'

%table#movies
  %thead
    %tr
      %th{:class => ("hilite" if @sort == "title")}= link_to "Movie Title", movies_path( :sort => "title", :ratings => @checked_ratings), :id => "title_header" 
      %th Rating
      %th{:class => ("hilite" if @sort == "release_date")}= link_to "Release Date", movies_path( :sort => "release_date", :ratings => @checked_ratings), :id => "release_date_header"
      %th More Info
  %tbody
    - @movies.each do |movie|
      %tr
        %td= movie.title 
        %td= movie.rating
        %td= movie.release_date
        %td= link_to "More about #{movie.title}", movie_path(movie)

= link_to 'Add new movie', new_movie_path

#This is my Controller

    class MoviesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    id = params[:id] # retrieve movie ID from URI route
    @movie = Movie.find(id) # look up movie by unique ID
    # will render app/views/movies/show.<extension> by default
  end

  def index
    #get all the ratings available 
    @all_ratings = Movie.all_ratings
    @checked_ratings = (params[:ratings].present? ? params[:ratings] : [])
    @sort = params[:sort]
    @movies = Movie.scoped

    if @sort && Movie.attribute_names.include?(@sort)
      @movies = @movies.order @sort
    end
    id @checked_ratings.empty?
      @checked_ratings = @all_ratings
    end
    unless @checked_ratings.empty?
      @movies = @movies.where :rating => @checked_ratings.keys
    end
  end

  def new
    # default: render 'new' template
  end

  def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end

  def edit
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @movie = Movie.find params[:id]
    @movie.update_attributes!(params[:movie])
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully updated."
    redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
  end

  def destroy
    @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
    @movie.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Movie '#{@movie.title}' deleted."
    redirect_to movies_path
  end
end
```

In the controller, I set the `@checked_rating` to be `@all_rating` if the `@checked.rating` is empty but it does not do anything. 
I tried putting `:checked => true` in the `index.html.haml` on the `check_box_tag` but that makes the checkboxes checked everytime the page is refreshed.
Everytime I check a particular checkbox and hit refresh button the page loads with all the checkboxes checked.

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to edit the ratings in the `index` action? Editing values is usually done in the `edit` action.

Comment: my intention was not to edit them but I want to check all the checkboxes when the page is loaded for the first time.

Comment: What's the purpose of having the check boxes checked only the first time the page is loaded? I'm not understanding the use-case here.

Comment: Because the first time page loads all the movies are shown and hence all the checkboxes are supposed to be checked. Then if we uncheck any checkbox and click the refresh button then only the movies with checked rating will be shown.

Comment: There are some very hacky ways to do that with cookies or session variables + AJAX, but you may want to re-think what you're really trying to accomplish here. Refreshing a page sends a brand new GET request to the server without any params, so it will be difficult to accomplish what you're trying to do in a RESTful way.

Comment: I figured out the checkboxes being checked first time the page loads. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what do you exactly meant by RESTful way? Thanks in advance

Comment: @BrendanBenson, what are talking about? He's just wants to change which movies are shown in the index action of his `MoviesController` based on the fact if a few checkboxes are checked or not. What's not RESTful about that??

Comment: @user1760920, don't worry about Brendan's comment about RESTful. It doesn't make any sense. What did you do to get it working?

Comment: @Mischa My apologies - I was confused when user1760920 mentioned refreshing the page. I missed the fact that there was a button named "Refresh."

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage + JavaScript to achieve this. On page load, check for the value of a property from the localstorage. If the value is set, don't check the boxes. If the values is not set, check all the boxes and set the value in localstorage.

Varun